# file.Read() stops the program until a a new content is added to the file. How to skip this line if there is no new content?

Tags: python, file

I am writing a python program in Linux that reads the mouse position from a system file. Everything works perfectly but when the mouse stops (no data is added to the file) the program stops at the Read function and waits for a new data to come to proceed. How can I let the program skip the Read function if it is going to wait?

Here is the code:

```
import struct

file = open( "/dev/input/mouse1", "rb" )

def getMouseEvent():  
    
    #check before reading if there is a content, since otherwise the program will stop at the next line until a new data is available (the mouse moves)
    buf = file.read(3)
    x,y = struct.unpack( "bb", buf[1:] )
    print ("x: %d, y: %d\n" % (x, y) )


while( 1 ):
    getMouseEvent()

file.close()
```

what I want is something like:

```
def getMouseEvent():  
    
    if(ThereIsData):
        buf = file.read(3)
        x,y = struct.unpack( "bb", buf[1:] )
        print ("x: %d, y: %d\n" % (x, y) )
    else:
        print('Skipped reading')
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific use-case, you can just set the fd to non-blocking:

```py
>>> g = open('/dev/input/mouse1', 'rb')
>>> g.read(1) # blocks here, had to C-c
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> import os; os.set_blocking(g.fileno(), False)
>>> g.read(1)
>>>
```

You can also use [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html?highlight=select#module-select) for `ThereIsData`, however that's not sufficient on its own: the device would be considered readable if there's any data available, but if there's only 1 byte available, you're requesting 3, and the device is in blocking mode... it's going to block until 3 bytes are available. So while it would avoid sprurious reads (which is good) and busy looping (because you can add a timeout to `select` so literally nothing happens if the device is not ready) that's not quite sufficient.

Though I guess it might be good enough for your needs here.